# Accordion dropdown selection

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using the accordion class to display some data in tables. My code loops through all the table rows and assigns them to an accordion dropdown. My problem is when I select one accordion header they all expand/collapse instead of just the one I clicked on.

```
  <div class="accordion" id="qc_inspection">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h1 class="accordion-header">
        <button class="accordion-button d-block text-center" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <h1 class="display-6">{{table['inspection']}}</h1>
        </button>
      </h1>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"
                value="{{ request.form['weight'] }}"></input>
          {{table['min']}} to {{table['max']}} grams
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Code works fine if I create each collapsible row independently and take the for loop out, but the number of rows changes depending on the table selected so that will not work.

Comment: Its because your id matches to all accordion. Try to make unique ids for the accordion. The key is data-bs-target="#collapseOne"

Comment: thanks! I set the data-bs-target="#a{{table['id']}}" and the id="a{{table['id']}}" and it worked! for some reason it did not like just a numeric value, which is why I added the "a" in front of the table['id']

Comment: Id and classname should not start with numerical value. So prefixing a is a good option

Answer (score 0):

assigning a unique value to data-bs-target and the accordion body id worked. it does not like just numeric values so I added "a" in front of the value. See working code below:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h1 class="accordion-header">
      <button class="accordion-button d-block text-center" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#a{{table['id']}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <h1 class="display-6">{{table['inspection']}}</h1>
      </button>
    </h1>
    <div id="a{{table['id']}}" class="accordion-collapse">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Weight" class="form-control"
              value="{{ request.form['weight'] }}"></input>
        {{table['min']}} to {{table['max']}} grams
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```